# Using the canvas element in HTML5

Tags: html

I'm trying to put together a website using HTML5. I'm attempting to use the canvas element with Javascript. I'm looking at a youtube video I'm certain that I'm following everything correctly, but I'm not getting anything. Can someone look over the code and see if I'm missing anything.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
    window.onload=loader;
    function loader()
    {
      var canvasI = document.getElementById("forcanvas");
      var canvasII = canvasI.getContext("2d");  
      canvasII.fillStyle ="rgba(0, 0, 200, 1)”;
      canvasII.fillRect(30, 30, 75, 70);
    }

</script>


</head>

<body>


<canvas id="forcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probable because you have `”` instead of `"` in several places. Otherwise it works.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `”` instead of `"`

try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=loader;
    function loader()
    {
      var canvasI = document.getElementById("forcanvas");
      var canvasII = canvasI.getContext("2d");  
      canvasII.fillStyle ="rgba(0, 0, 200, 1)";
      canvasII.fillRect(30, 30, 75, 70);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="forcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```